# Downvoting a low quality question results in incorrect review

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I just got a review ban for downvoting this question in "First posts":

[NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609738/ndk-resolution-outcome-project-settings-gradle-model-version-5-4-1-ndk-versio)

Sure it has a lot of upvotes - probably because this is something that bothers a lot of people. On the other hand - it's poorly worded and offers very little information - basically it's just "I got this error, help me".

Was a downvote warranted here?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23957104 . Question does not look good at all to me

Comment: I can't say how good/important the question is for a android dev, but it doesn't seem to be a good choice for a audit. Especially because it was resolved in comments by reimporting the project. I probably would have tried to close as off-topic -> no repro.

Comment: Note that this type of question, _I upgraded my software and suddenly got this error doing something that previously worked fine_, often gets lots of views and upvotes if it's a common occurrence, and certainly should not be removed from the site if it includes enough information to reproduce the issue. I generally hit _Skip_ on IDE-related questions since judging the quality is very hard

Comment: Note that you rarely get a review ban for a single failed audit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd have to disagree<sup>1</sup> here, the question seems fine.

> it's poorly worded [...]

Sure, but it isn't *that* poorly worded that it can't be edited into shape.

<sup>(It has now been reworded to make it easier to read)</sup>

> [...] offers very little information

- It tells us when the error occurred (after updating Android Studio and Gradle)
- It provides an error message
- It provides both the version they updated to and from (3.5 and 3.4.2)
- It provides at least one attempt to fix the issue (downgrading back to 3.4.2)

I'm not sure what else is wanted with these types of issues?

> Was a downvote warranted here?

IMHO, I wouldn't have down-voted it.

With all that said, **I don't think you should've been penalized for down-voting it** because it has always been believed that people can vote as they please.

One man's trash is another man's treasure.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's fine that we disagree, that's why voting exists.